# Show that $|\frac{e^{z}-1}{z}|$ is bounded on every half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $|\frac{e^{z}-1}{z}|$ is bounded on every half-plane $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:\text{Re }z\leq c\}$.

It is clear that the numerator alone is bounded. How do we deal with the $\frac{1}{z}$ term? Would be grateful for a hint on this. Thanks.

Comment: What do you know about the exponential function? Taylor series would be helpful...

Comment: What about using $\lim\limits_{z\to0}\frac{e^z-1}{z}=1$?

Comment: To get $Re(z)<c$ into the estimate, use $|e^z-1|=e^{Re\,z}\,|1-e^{-z}|=2e^{Re\,z/2}|\sinh(z/2)|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside some disk containing the origin, say $D(0,1)$, it is easily bounded:
$$\left|{e^z - 1 \over z}\right| \leqslant {\left|e^z\right| + 1 \over \left|z\right|} \leqslant e^{\operatorname{Re} c} + 1$$
Inside $D(0,1)$ it is also bounded because ${e^z - 1 \over z}$ extends continuously at $z=0$ (so it is bounded just by compactness).